# Search a value in range

Tags: google-sheets

I have this [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hMFW6Qwnmt9rb8O8-oVTFRRKBJMANlXjPnKXWwQzOfI/edit#gid=0).
I need to make search on this sheet.
It is necessary to make it so that when I enter a value from the range B1:S54 into cell V2, I get in cell V3 the Sector number that corresponds to the row in which this value is located.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below formula- (See your sheet).

```
=FILTER(A1:A54;MMULT(--(B1:S54=V2);SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B1:S1))))
```

[image]

Comment: I added one more question in my first post, maybe you can help me with it

Comment: It would be better if you ask a separate question on it.

Comment: Okay. This is exactly what I did. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this. Here is one, using string matching:

```
=array_constrain( 
  iferror( 
    filter( 
      A1:A; 
      regexmatch( 
        transpose( query( " " & transpose( substitute(trim(B1:S); " "; "_") & " " ); ""; 9^9 ) ); 
        " " & trim(V2) & " " 
      ) 
    ); 
    "(no match)" 
  ); 
  counta(A1:A); 
  1 
)
```

Note that your data repeats some values such as 1741 in more than one sector. The formula will list all matching sectors.