# Finding a value from a range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my test [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hMFW6Qwnmt9rb8O8-oVTFRRKBJMANlXjPnKXWwQzOfI/edit#gid=0).
I need to do a search on this table using Google Apps Script.
For example, the page will have `<input>`, I enter there a number or text from the range B1:S54 of my sheet and when I click on the button, I get the result in the form of the Sector number, in row of which this number or text is located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got two answers how to do this with a spreadsheet formula in the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67379736/13045193). To get the formula result in Google Apps Script, use `sheet.getRange('V3').getValue()`.

If your intention is to implement a search dialog box completely in Google Apps Script, use this:

```
function findSector(key) {
  const data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Main!A1:S').getValues();
  const sectors = data.map(row => row.shift());
  return sectors.filter((sector, index) => data[index].some(value => value === key));
}
```

The function will return an array that lists matching sectors. To get just the first result, use `const result = findSector('item12')[0]`.